# Parametric integral

Tags: integration

The task is to compute

$$\int\limits_0^\pi \frac{\sin^{n-1}(x)}{(1+k\ \cos x)^n} dx$$

through Euler integrals. $0<|k|<1$

Tangent half-angle substitution ($t=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$) gives the following:

$$I=2\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{(2t)^{n-1}}{(1+k+(k-1)t^2)^n} dt$$

Comment: Try $t=cosx$:
$$\int_{1}^{-1}\frac{(1-t^2)^{\frac{n-1}2}dt}{(1+kt)^n}$$

Comment: the solution containes the Gamma -function

Comment: Tried $z=(1-t)/(1+kt)$ and $z=(1+t)/(1+kt)$ after $t = cos(x)$, nothing fits.

Comment: for $n$ odd, your second integral can be evaluated by a standard application of the residue theorem

Comment: and in general, throug a sub $\frac{k-1}{1+k}t^2=q$ this straightforwardly maps onto a standard representation of Euler's Beta function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties